# How to remove items name in scrapy function?

Tags: python, scrapy

When running the coding, it gives me items price but the items name is same. Means it gives `transcription_price: 245` and then `transcription_price: 240`. There should be `caption_price` and `transcription_price`. Why and how to solve this issue?

```
import scrapy
from .. items import FetchingItem
import re

class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'Site'
start_urls = ['https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription',
          'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/captions']

def parse(self, response):
    items = FetchingItem()
    Transcription_price = response.css('#middle-benefit .mt1::text').extract()

    items['Transcription_price'] = Transcription_price

    def next_parse(self, response):
        other_items = FetchingItem()
        Caption_price = response.css('#middle-benefit .mt1::text').extract()

        other_items['Caption_price'] = Caption_price
        yield other_items

    yield items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never reaches the method `self.next_parse`. By default Scrapy calls the callback `self.parse` to each URL in `self.start_urls`.
You can use a customized callback by overriding the method `start_requests`.

Here is how you do it:

```
import scrapy
from .. items import FetchingItem
import re

class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Site'

    def start_requests(self):
        return [
            scrapy.Request('https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription', callback=self.parse_transcription),
            scrapy.Request('https://www.rev.com/freelancers/captions', callback=self.parse_caption)
        ]

    def parse_transcription(self, response):
        items = FetchingItem()
        Transcription_price = response.css('#middle-benefit .mt1::text').extract()

        items['Transcription_price'] = Transcription_price
        yield items

    def parse_caption(self, response):
        other_items = FetchingItem()
        Caption_price = response.css('#middle-benefit .mt1::text').extract()

        other_items['Caption_price'] = Caption_price
        yield other_items
```

See the [Spider documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) for more information.